# MDM commands metadata

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, mdm

I'm new in MDM servers at all.
I'm working with [nanomdm](https://github.com/micromdm/nanomdm) server. Can I add my own metadata to the commands or payload, which send to the device? For example, UDID,  that will be readed later by my mobile application and how can my mobile application do that? Or can I get UDID, which used in nanomdm, by my mobile application in another way?

Like that:

```xml
...
<key>PayloadContent</key>
  <array>
      <dict>
          <key>UDID</key>
        <string>MY_UDID</string>
      </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
      <string>Profile Removal</string>
      <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
...
```

```swift
udid = get_from_profile()
```

Answer (score 0):

One your iOS device has been registered with your MDM, you can provide configuration to an iOS app using the Settings command.

The app must first be "managed" by the MDM. This can be accomplished using the "InstallApplication" command. Once you allow the app to be managed, using the Settings command with a payload containing your devices UUID.